# Using a network drive as git repository

Tags: windows, git, shared-directory

So, I've created a git repository on the networked drive:

```
git init --bare --shared
```

and that works fine. Then, I clone it to a local drive with

```
git clone z:/testgit
```

and that also works fine. Then I add a file, stage, and commit

```
git stage *
git commit -m "test commit"
```

and that ALSO works fine. BUT! When I try to push to the origin, I get this error.

```
git push origin
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 225 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/f3/e6e90a7465421306fae05c18153260973542e3: Permission denied
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To z:/testgit14
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'z:/testgit'
```

When attempting to use git stage * directly on the server (on a non --bare git project) I get similar errors.

I have full access to the drive in file explorer, and even able to initialize the repository with git. SSH shouldn't even apply here since it's not a server, it's a networked drive. Everything I've read about git says that this should work. I've read dozens of "how to's" that all say these exact steps, but no one complaining about permission denied, UNLESS they're talking about SSH public keys missing on servers (which, as I've said, shouldn't apply).

What permissions am I missing? Where should I look for and set the proper permissions?

Comment: I don't do Windows, so I'm not sure what's going on, but the "permission denied" means that you are not allowed to write to the network-shared drive. Which is interesting since presumably you wrote to it just a moment ago to create the bare repo. Note that when both repositories are local (not using ssh nor http), it's your own Git that spawns processes to act as the "other Git" talking to the "other repo", so it will likely have something to do with that. In any case this sounds like a Windows Networked Drives quesion, not really a Git question.

Comment: Try adding `Everyone` to the folder/file access.

Comment: user9000, that's exactly what it's setup as. The drive has given everyone full permissions.

Comment: if you set `transfer.unpackLimit` on your remote repository to 1, does the error still happen during push?

Comment: The "permission denied" message can also mean that the file in question is locked by other program. I'd say it is the real reason in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you try to create the file that `git` is complaining about?

```
echo test > ./objects/f3/e6e90a7465421306fae05c18153260973542e3
```

It's possible that `git` is creating a new folder (`f3`) and the folder is not getting the correct permissions, either due to ACL inheritance misconfiguration or because the local machine is trying to adjust the permissions on newly created folders and getting it wrong.

If it were Linux, it could be because the network drive was connected with the wrong mount options, or the umask was set incorrectly, but I'm not sure whether those are available to be changed on a Windows machine.